# Notation for two variables with same dimensions

Tags: dimensional-analysis, notation

What symbol represents "has the dimensions of", as in "x has the dimensions of d"? Does such a symbol exist?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a symbol for that exact purpose. I'd just write "x has the same dimensions as d".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Square bracket notation for dimensions and units: usage and conventions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77690/)

Answer (score 1):

Some people use square brackets to denote dimension. I'm not 100% sure if they are used in this case.

I would use these if you are desperate but be explicit and don't assume the reader understands.

R = $[J] [K^{-1}] [mol^{-1}]$

edit: on the other hand

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem

Buckingham Pi Theorem uses dimensional analysis, wikipedia uses lower case to denote the dimensions. I think that is confusing at first sight.