# Question about units of mass, $M = (L^{3})(T^{-2})$?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, maxwell-equations

In section 5 of the "Preliminary: On the measurement of quantities" chapter (page 3) in "A treatise on electricity and magnetism" Maxwell uses, total length, $s=mt^{2}/{2r^{2}}$to show that $m=2sr^{2}/{t^2}$ is in units of Length cubed over Time squared.

This is the first I have encountered this way of looking at mass and am wondering:

1. Is this just per-relativity nonsense?
2. Does mass being "length cubed over time squared" have any meaning?

Comment: Where exactly in the book does this show up? I think some context is necessary to make sense of it.

Comment: This can be true in natural units, but it's not much of an observation in that system.

Answer (score 4):

Maxwell is being misunderstood.  First, Maxwell makes very clear that length, time and mass are the fundamental types of units.  Then he discusses a totally different convention that isn't used today, saying "in the astronomical system, the unit of mass is defined with respect to its attractive power".  In other words, Maxwell is talking about a concept of mass where G is incorporated into the definition of mass.

Only in this context does Maxwell go on to state:

"For acceleration due to the attraction of a mass m at a distance r is by Newton's Law $\frac{m}{r^2}$".  Then Maxwell takes $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ and substitutes $\frac{m}{r^2}$ for a.

So to anwser the questions:

> 1.Is this just per-relativity nonsense?

No, it has nothing to do with relativity.  The treatise was written well before Einstein's theories of relativity.

> 2.Does mass being "length cubed over time squared" have any meaning?

Yes, in the context of Maxwell's discussion of a different definition of mass, which incorporates G into the definition, it is the correct unit of mass.

Comment: So, this is equivalent to the relationship between SI and Gaussian units for E&M? Interesting.

Comment: yes, that's what Stan Liou is saying in his answer.  Stan had already said what I was trying to say, in a slightly different way, but I didn't realize it at first.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is Maxwell's text:

> If, as in the astronomical system, the unit of mass is defined with respect to its attractive power, the dimensions of $[M]$ are $[L^3T^{-2}]$.

To motivate this, it is perhaps useful to be aware of some of the different systems of units for electromagnetism used historically. One of the units of charge commonly in use was the $\mathrm{esu}$ (electrostatic unit) aka $\mathrm{statC}$ (statCoulomb) based on taking the coefficient of Coulomb's law to be unitless:
$$F = \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}\text{.}$$
Thus, by dimensional analysis, $[F] = [MLT^{-2}]$ implies that the unit of charge has dimension
$$[Q] = [M^{1/2}L^{3/2}T^{-1}]\mathrm{.}$$
Thus, it is clear that Maxwell is simply doing the same thing for gravity--considering a system of units in which "mass is defined with respect to its attractive power", i.e., through Newton's law of gravitation
$$F = \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}\text{,}$$
and so $[F] = [MLT^{-2}] = [M^2L^{-2}]$ implies that $$[M] = [L^3T^{-2}]\text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider two bodies, $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}.$
From Newton laws, we have:
$$F=G\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{s^{2}}\tag1 $$
 but 
$$F =m_{1}a,\tag2$$ 
and combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ two we obtain
$$m_{1}a=G\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{s^{2}}.\tag3$$
We also know that
$$ a=\frac{s}{t^{2}}.$$
Then, $(3)$ becomes
$$m_{1}\frac{s}{t^{2}}=G\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{s^{2}},$$
which, after a little bit of algebra, gives you
$$ m_{2}=G\frac{s^{3}}{t^{2}},$$
and this can be written, using dimensional analysis, as
$$ [m_{2}]=[s^{3}][t^{-2}].$$

Comment: I sort of see what you're trying to do here, I think, but it's really sloppy. Your $G$ keeps appearing and disappearing, which spoils the logic. Also, it looks like you switch from $r$ to $s$, and you're inconsistent in distinguishing units from variables.

Comment: If you read carefully, you will see that I said using dimensional analysis, $6$ becomes the final result. I don't think you know what you talking about here since you seem not to understand what a dimensional analysis is.Also please read Maxwell work to how dimensional analysis used in explaining this.

Comment: I can't believe that someone down-voted me for answering correctly.

Comment: Use `tag{1}` not those horrible dots, but also why tag an equation you don't reference? And unless you are using natural units, $G$ is a dimensional constant.

Comment: I upvoted it because it does point towards the correct answer, but it is very confusedly explained. In fact what Maxwell is doing is defining a new unit for which there is no $G$ in Newton's law.

Comment: Well... "very confusedly explained" is kind of the textbook criterion to downvote something... ("unclear or not useful")

Comment: Is it "very confusedly explained" because it is explained poorly or it is you?

Answer (score -1):

I am in agreement with the comment that "Maxwell is talking about a concept of mass where G is incorporated into the definition of mass". There is a system of units out there which is not well known, where all physical properties are broken down into distance (L) and time (T) units.  In that system, mass (M) = (L^1)(T^-6) and G = (L^2)(T^4).  The combination of G X M = (L^3) (T^-2) gives the same result as in  Maxwell's papers.