# What is $[\mathrm{J}]$ supposed to denote in this case?

Tags: optics, dimensional-analysis, photonics

I am currently studying *Laser Systems Engineering* by Keith Kasunic. Chapter **1.2 Laser Engineering** says the following:

> If the energy of the incident electromagnetic field more-or-less matches that of the electron’s excited state energy $E_2$ compared with some lower-energy state $E_1$, then there is a high probability the electron will give up its energy in the form of a stimulated photon whose energy $E_p$ in Fig. 1.9(a) is
> $$E_p = E_2 - E_1 = h \nu = \dfrac{h c}{\lambda} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [\mathrm{J}] \tag{1.2}$$
> where $h = 6.626 \times 10^{-34}$ J-sec is Planck’s constant.

What is $[\mathrm{J}]$ supposed to denote in this case? I read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77690/141502) relevant question on square brackets in dimensional analysis, but I don't think it clarifies what it means in this particular case.

Comment: It means (1.2) is expressed in Joules.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's all? There isn't some additional meaning given by the square brackets? Why wouldn't the author just leave it as $\mathrm{J}$, then?

Comment: depends on the authors I guess.  It's sometimes indicated so that in particular the  value of hbar is taken to be in correct numerical value in Joules.

Comment: The [J] is pointless and confusing, since equations like 1.2 are true in *any* units.

Comment: @G.Smith What do you mean that such equations are true "in any units"?

Comment: Consider something simpler. The equation $x=vt$ does not need an [m] next to it because $x$ does not have to be measured in meters. You can measure $x$ in furlongs and $t$ in fortnights, or any other units that you find convenient, and $x=vt$ will still be true.

Comment: @G.Smith Oh, ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: I suppose that once the value of the Planck constant is specified (with units) as was done here, then it follows that the energy will be in Joules (if $\nu$ is in inverse seconds) but I agree with @G.Smith it's not terribly illuminating to include the [J].

Comment: And if $c$ is in meters per second. And if you don’t do any unit conversions. I think the [J] may be there as a “helpful reminder” because this is a book for engineers rather than physicists. Do they put the SI unit for the quantity being computed next to every equation, or just this one?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero This is awfully confusing. How does that follow? If $h$ is in J-sec, $\nu$ is in $s^{-1}$, and $c$ is in $m \cdot s^{-1}$, then don't we end up with final units of J-sec (by cancellation) instead of just J?

Comment: Clearly there's a typo somewhere as $h\nu \ne h c/\nu$.  I think the last one should be $h c/\lambda$ since $\lambda \nu =c$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Oh, you're right; that was my typo! Sorry about that. The units make sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$E_p = E_2 - E_1 = h \nu = \dfrac{h c}{\lambda} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [\mathrm{J}] \tag{1.2}$$
> where $h = 6.626 \times 10^{-34}$ J-sec is Planck’s constant.

Another way of writing this is,

$$E_p/J = E_2 - E_1 = h \nu = \dfrac{h c}{\lambda} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \tag{1.3}.$$

It means that $E_p$ is expressed in units of $Joules$, so $E_p/J$ is $E_p$ per unit $J$.